# Removing ambiguity from grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

Ambiguous grammar:

E -> UV | EBE | V | [E]

V -> a | b

U -> < | >

B -> ? | ! | @

Some information:

Order of precedence: ? < ! < @, with unary operators (<,>) being the highest

Binary operators ?, !, @ are right associative.

My attempt:

E -> UV | EBT | V | [E]

T -> E

V -> a | b

U -> < | >

B -> ? | B1

B1 -> ! | B2

B2 -> @

I'm not sure if I left out some corner cases during my conversion. Appreciate if you guys can point some mistakes out and offer some hints.

Answer (score 0):

`E -> UV | EBE | V | [E]
V -> a | b
U -> < | >
B -> ? | ! | @`

> Order of precedence: ? < ! < @, with unary operators (<,>) being the
>   highest.
>
> Binary operators ?, !, @ are right associative.

I was confused about your order of precedence, because it implies `!` is higher precedence than `>`.

So assuming this order of precedence:

`a,b,<,>,?,!,@`

I would note that unambiguous grammars are all about using intermediary characters, normally more than the ambiguous grammars, to ensure that there is a standard procedure of steps to reach a certain terminal symbol, i.e. each string will have the same parse tree. Highest precedence means that it is the closest conversion to the final non-terminal to terminal symbol conversion.

My answer would be:

`E -> V?E | V!E | V@E | [E] //Right associativity = right recursive
V-> <V | >V | E | T | a | b
T-> a | b | E`

However very difficult to know without knowing your target string and accepted/not accepted.